# Suggested Edits: Is it OK to fix obvious typing mistakes in commands and code blocks?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

While editing "Suggested Edits" questions, Is it OK to fix obvious typing mistakes in commands and code blocks provided by the OP?

On one hand, this is an obvious typo.

On second hand, what if it's not? What if this typo is somehow related to the problem?

In the example below, the OP posted an obvious typing mistake. He couldn't have got the error message provided otherwise. But still, feels like I'm corrupting the question somehow.

What do you guys think?

Here's the example:

**Before** my edit:

---

[image]

**After** my edit:

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> He couldn't have got the error message provided otherwise.

Then, yes, you should fix the typo.

More generally, if you have ample evidence that it *is* a simple typo (either because you're an expert in the language/technology or because you have clarification from the asker in a comment), then you should go ahead and fix the typo.

If you aren't sure, or it's ambiguous, then you should *not* fix typos in code/commands.

There is this line of thinking that supposes code blocks are somehow "off limits" to editors. It's a debate that gets played out periodically here on Meta. I think it's broadly nonsense. However, there is a grain of truth to it, and that's that you need to exercise additional caution when editing code. Make sure you know what you're doing! If you aren't sure, then err on the side of not doing it.